# Migrate androidTest to Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso, android-compose-textfield

We are in the process of migrating our Android app to Jetpack Compose.

In our legacy Views-based app, we have a lot of `androidTest` tests, running on the emulator, using Espresso.

Most of our tests heavily use the Espresso `withId()` matcher. But of course since Composables don't have ids as Views do, we have a problem.
Is there a way to assign ids to composables, and reuse existing Espresso tests using `withId()`?
If it's not possible or somehow a bad approach, what would be the right way to search for a specific UI element on screen and click on it for instance?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the [**`testTag`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#testtag) modifier to your composables.
Something like:

```
   Button(modifier = Modifier.testTag("myButton"), onClick = {}) {
         Text("myButton")
   }
```

and then you can use it with:

```
   rule.onNodeWithTag("myButton")
        .assertIsEnabled()
```

Comment: Ah ah, thanks! I just found it by myself but you were faster to answer! BTW, looks like you are the one answering all my compose questions lately, thank's a lot!!